# How do I style book titles in a block of italicized text?

Tags: writing-style, book-title, titles, italics

Book titles, among others, are commonly written in italics.

> She had read this quote in *Pride and Prejudice*.

But what should I do if a title appears in a block of text that is already italicized, such as a character's thoughts?

Do I reverse the italics?

> *I've read this quote in* Pride and Prejudice, she thought.

Do I use quotation marks, instead?

> *I've read this quote in "Pride and Prejudice,"* she thought.

Or do I use another approach altogether?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reverse the italics to roman as you've done in the first example.